# Как к карусели прикрутить дополнительные переключатели элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, карусель

Есть `owl carousel`, в которой используется свойство `stagePadding` для видимости кусочков элементов. Как сделать так, чтобы помимо переключателей next|prev, карусель переключалась также при клике на выступы элементов справа и слева соответственно? [переходите по фидлу - поймете](https://jsfiddle.net/rtvc5exr/8/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  stagePadding: 100,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 2000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    470: {
      items: 3
    },
    768: {
      items: 4
    },
    1199: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
});
$('.owl-carousel').find('.owl-item.active').prev(':not(.active)').css('background-color', 'red');
$('.owl-carousel').find('.owl-item.active').next(':not(.active)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
  height: 10rem;
  background: #4DC7A0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>6</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>7</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>8</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>9</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>10</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>11</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>12</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что за выступы?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский перейдите по ссылке фидла - слева и справа видна только часть элемента

Comment: нет в фидле никаких выступов

Comment: @Jean-Claude специально для вас добавил в описание картинку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html) нужно добавить кнопки по такому принципу:

```
// Go to the next item
$('.customNextBtn').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})
// Go to the previous item
$('.customPrevBtn').click(function() {
    // With optional speed parameter
    // Parameters has to be in square bracket '[]'
    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
})
```

Итоговое решение - [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/rtvc5exr/10/)

Comment: а где там дополнительные переключатели ? я в примере добавил - у тебя нету их

Comment: @Geyan я ничего не говорил по поводу их видимости - работают, как будто переключение срабатывает по элементу, а не переключателю

Answer (score 1):

Ну решение конечно топорное , в документации особенно по этому поводу ни чего нету но для .owl-prev,.owl-next {сделал позиционированние и прозрачность}

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
    height: 10rem;
    background: #4DC7A0;
    padding: 1rem;
    position:relative;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-prev{
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  display:block;
  height:99%;
  width:90px;
  background:red;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-next{
  position:absolute;
  top:0; right:0;
  display:block;
  height:99%;
  width:90px;
  background:red;
}
.owl-prev,.owl-next{
 opacity:0;
}
```

Вот Дэмо : https://jsfiddle.net/Geyan/rtvc5exr/9/

Comment: эмм, не совсем.. мне нужно, как и написано в вопросе, дополнительные именно переключатели, чтобы были как стрелки, по которым переключаешь, так и выступы. если бы нужно было просто выступами переключать - вопрос бы не стоял

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rtvc5exr/11/  последний вариант , наведи на лево и потом на право , работает в общем

Comment: да, только я добрался до решения немного раньше снизу